# How to check connection from Python to Neo4j

Tags: python, python-3.x, neo4j, py2neo

I'm doing a microservice in **Python 3.7** that connects to a **Neo4j** database. It's the first time I work connecting Python with Neo4j and I'm using **py2neo version 4.3.0.**
Everything works OK, but now to adhere to the standard, I need to create a healthcheck to verify the connection to the Database.
I wanted to use the

```
from py2neo import Graph, Database
```

and use

```
db = Database ("bolt: // localhost: 7474", auth = ("neo4j", "xxxx"))
```

and

```
db.kernel_version (Dont work)
```

but with this I do not verify that there is connection is up. Does anybody have any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If checking the kernel version doesn't work then the connection is not ok.  Below is a script to check if the connection from python to neo4j (via py2neo) is up and running.

```
from py2neo import Graph
graph = Graph("bolt://localhost:7687", auth=("neo4j", "xxxxx"))
try:
    graph.run("Match () Return 1 Limit 1")
    print('ok')
except Exception:
    print('not ok')
```

Comment: Thanks you very much AnonyXmous.
When i try to use that (db.kernel_version), the program dont respond. It freezes, so I wanted to know if there was some other method.

Comment: Then it is not connection to neo4j but your program. You can hack py2neo and put debug somewhere. If not working, try uninstall/install py2neo.

Comment: I already have a process that works. I connect in the following way 
`graph = Graph(db_str, auth=("neo4j", "xxxx"))`
and execute the following query
`graph.run("MATCH (roots:" + elementType +  "{ID:'" + elementName + "'})-[*]->leaves return count(leaves)")`
 and all ok.
Now I want to verify that this connection is up. With db.kernel_version I could not

Comment: then you can run/execute a dummy query and if that query returns data, then your db connection is working well. See my updated answer.

Comment: You are a crack anonyXmouS!
Thank you very much, it worked perfect!

Comment: You're welc. Glad to help. Please accept my answer by clicking on the check button. Thanks.